# How to obtain the current session in hibernate

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, criteria

I'm trying to get the current session in hibernate to create a criteria Query, but I'm getting an error.

Here is my code:

datasource.xml:

```
    <bean id="entityManagerFactory"
    class="org.springframework.orm.jpa.LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean">
    <property name="jpaVendorAdapter" ref="jpaVendorAdapter" />
    <property name="dataSource" ref="dataSource" />
    <property name="persistenceUnitName" ref="persistenceUnit" />
    <property name="jpaProperties" ref="jpaProperties" />
</bean>

<bean id="sessionFactory"
    class="org.springframework.orm.hibernate4.LocalSessionFactoryBean">
    <property name="dataSource" ref="dataSource" />
</bean>

<bean id="transactionManager" class="org.springframework.orm.jpa.JpaTransactionManager">
    <property name="entityManagerFactory" ref="entityManagerFactory" />
    <property name="dataSource" ref="dataSource" />
    <property name="globalRollbackOnParticipationFailure" value="true" />
</bean>

<bean id="jpaVendorAdapter"
    class="org.springframework.orm.jpa.vendor.HibernateJpaVendorAdapter">
    <property name="databasePlatform" ref="sqlDialect" />
</bean>
```

class java:

```
    @Autowired
    private SessionFactory  sessionFactory;
    Session session = sessionFactory.getCurrentSession();

    FullTextEntityManager fullTextEntityManager = Search.getFullTextEntityManager(em);
    List<Product> bookResult = new ArrayList<>();
    try {
        // This will ensure that index for already inserted data is created.
        fullTextEntityManager.createIndexer().startAndWait();
        QueryBuilder qb = fullTextEntityManager.getSearchFactory().buildQueryBuilder().forEntity(Product.class).get();
    org.apache.lucene.search.Query query = qb.keyword().onFields("name").matching("cocacola").createQuery();
        javax.persistence.Query jpaQuery = fullTextEntityManager.createFullTextQuery(query, Product.class);

        Criteria criteria = session.createCriteria(Product.class);
        criteria.add(Restrictions.eq("category.supermarket", "mercadona"));

        List<Product> productos = criteria.list();
```

But get this error:

> org.hibernate.HibernateException: No Session found for current thread
>     at
>   org.springframework.orm.hibernate4.SpringSessionContext.currentSession(SpringSessionContext.java:106)

How do I solve this?

Comment: Why you are working with Hibernate 4 and JPA, together? Has no sense..

Comment: sessionFactory.getCurrentSession(); has to called from a transactional method. Probably adding @Transactional on the method will work.

Comment: I add @Transactional, but not work. I use this template because the teacher has given us

Answer (score 0):

Have you add to your servlet-context.xml

```
<tx:annotation-driven transaction-manager="transactionManager" />
```

to use @Transaction?

And also check if @Autowired working right way for example `System.out.println(sessionFactory)` in your class.java to be sure that isn't null.

Comment: tx:annotation is present, I use @Transaction and not work. I change:
<bean id="transactionManager" class="org.springframework.orm.jpa.JpaTransactionManager"> to <bean id="transactionManager"
  class="org.springframework.orm.hibernate4.HibernateTransactionManager"> and now work, but criteria can not search correctly. solutions?